# Python - simple dataframe restructuring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, lreshape

I am struggling to restructure my dataframe in a simple and effective way.

The first dataframe 'new' is what I have and the desired dataframe is new2. I have been messing around with pivot, stack, unstack, set_index, reshape etc for a long time and still can't achieve this simple transformation. I keep getting either error messages or the wrong outcome. Could someone please help out?

What I have

```
data1 = [50, 60]
data2 = [100, 200]
year = [2015,2016]
new = pd.DataFrame({'product': data1, 'year':year, 'market':data2})
```

What I want

```
new2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['2015', '2016'])
new2.loc['market'] = data1
new2.loc['product'] = data2
```

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ZZO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last for remove column name add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.set_index('year').T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
         2015  2016
market    100   200
product    50    60
```